# The Sigmoid-Of-Tangent Removal Impact Problem Across Many Graphs In a Unit Square.

Tags: geometry, set-theory, graphing-functions

I have this problem; and to solve it, I want to erase the possibility of someone drawing a graph of the *sigmoid squashing* effect in a given scenario, as shown below.

Say there is this set, call it $J$. There is going to be the use of the term $-$ in here, so heads up.

$J$ is the set of all graphs in the domain $[0,1]$ and range $[n_0,n_1]$ where $n_0 >0$, $n_0 < 1$, $n_1 >0$, $n_1 < 1$ and obviously, $n_1 > n_0$

Now, picture the graph of this:

[image]

$$1/(1+1/e^{\tan(\pi(x-1/2))})$$

Create a subset that doesn't contain the following:

$$a(1/(1+1/e^{\tan(a\pi(x-1/2))}))$$ where a is any number in the range $[0,1]$.

Let the following exist. Let $J_{-\sigma_{\pi}}$ equal the subset that does *not* contain the above, and the subset that *does* contain the above but not $J_{-\sigma_{\pi}}$ is $J_{\sigma_{\pi}}$

Let also there be a distance $r$ that each point in the graph can be *away from, maximum* the *sigmoidal squish* and still be counted as $J_{\sigma_{\pi}}$. $r$ is our bias that helps avoid things *too* close to the *sigmoidal squish*.

What is the overall impact of switching someone from being able to graph any possible graph contained in $J$, all graphs inside a specific unit square, to only $J_{-\sigma_{\pi}}$, all graphs inside a specific unit square that *don't* contain that squashing effect, and what is a neat tidy deviation *r* that *doesn't* erase too many graphs? Is there a loophole that allows the *squashing effect* in other ways on the graph? And what does this all look like in math-speak?

Comment: I will also accept $a r$, $a^2 r$, $a^{\theta} r$ and so on, as long as the radius $r$ is there, or a replacement for $r$ that is elegant is given.

Comment: I apologize if this is not 100% clear. Impact is a general term, and mathematicians are familiar with exchanging surface areas (like pealing an orange), contours (like cutting and trading rope), etc. and having an equation that best represents that problem-- only they only need the math problem. What the question is asking is about *overall* impact.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to include a graphical representation (for the specific value $a=0.57$) of your sigmoid (by the way, what is the square you are referring to in the title ?), but your question (and even its context) confuse me and I musn't be alone. Please explain in a more straightforward way what your function is supposed not to do and **for which purpose** and the term "impact" doesn't evoke anything in this context, sorry. Would you mean that you **iterate** again and again this function or **invert** it ?

Comment: You can tell that what is graphed is governed by knowing two of three things: The container, the byproduct, and the containable. The approximations to get rid of the squashing effect from all graphs are iterated and tested again and again and the end result prevents the graph of the squish from showing up, but basically, the graphs being altered is part of a mini-game within a game I am making up. I would like to know how much taking a function that resides in nature so much and forbidding it from appearing in any graph a player would get to alter would change the subset and how they adapt.

Comment: The unit square is on a graph. from x=0 to x=1 and from y=0 to y=1.

Comment: I misclicked. I'm sorry. Please feel free to put it in.

Comment: Just included again under an improved form (the arbitrary case a=0.8 has a specific color)

Comment: A remark: $\tan(\pi(x-1/2)=-\cot \pi x$